# Why can't I write on MySQL with my javascript table creator questions to php variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```js
<center><a button onclick="myButton()" class="myButton">Inicio</a></center>
<script>
function myButton() 
{
do
 {
    var table = document.getElementById("myexam");
    var header = table.createTFoot();
    var pregunta = prompt("Cual es La pregunta");
 
 var row = header.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
 
 
 if (pregunta != null) 
  {
    cell.innerHTML = "<b> " + pregunta + "<br>";
  }
   var table = document.getElementById("myexam");
    var header = table.createTFoot();
    var respuesta_a = prompt("Cual es La respuesta A");
    /*<?php
     $respuesta_a = “<script> document.write(respuesta_a) </script>”;
     echo “respuesta_a = “.$respuesta_a;
    ?>*/
    var cell = row.insertCell(1);
     if (respuesta_a != null) 
     {
      cell.innerHTML = "<b> " + respuesta_a + "<br>";
     }
      var table = document.getElementById("myexam");
       var header = table.createTFoot();
       var respuesta_b = prompt("Cual es La respuesta B");
       /*<?php
        $respuesta_b = “<script> document.write(respuesta_b) </script>”;
        echo “respuesta_b = “.$respuesta_b;
       ?>*/ 
       var cell = row.insertCell(2);
       if (respuesta_b != null) 
        {
         cell.innerHTML = "<b> " + respuesta_b + "<br>";
        }
        var table = document.getElementById("myexam");
        var header = table.createTFoot();
        var respuesta_c = prompt("Cual es La respuesta C");
        /*<?php
         $respuesta_c = “<script> document.write(respuesta_c) </script>”;
         echo “respuesta_c = “.$respuesta_c;
        ?> */
        var cell = row.insertCell(3);
         if (respuesta_c != null) 
         {
          cell.innerHTML = "<b> " + respuesta_c + "<br>";
         }
        
         var table = document.getElementById("myexam");
          var header = table.createTFoot();
          var respuesta_d = prompt("Cual es La respuesta D");
          /*<?php
           $respuesta_d = “<script> document.write(respuesta_d) </script>”;
           echo “respuesta_d = “.$respuesta_d;
          ?> */
          var cell = row.insertCell(4);
          if (respuesta_d != null) 
          {
           cell.innerHTML = "<b> " + respuesta_d + "<br>";
          }
           var table = document.getElementById("myexam");
            var header = table.createTFoot();
            var respuesta_co = prompt("Cual es La respuesta Correcta");
            /*<?php
             $respuesta_co = “<script> document.write(respuesta_co) </script>”;
             echo “respuesta_co = “.$respuesta_co;
            ?> */
            var cell = row.insertCell(5);
            if (respuesta_co != null) 
             {
              cell.innerHTML = "<b> " + respuesta_co + "<br>";
             }
              answer = confirm ("Desea Agregar Otra pregunta?")
                                                       }
        while (answer)
}

</script>
```

```css
<style>

body { 
  color: blue; 
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
#rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 5px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 75px;    
}
.myButton {
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 14px -7px #3e7327;
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #77b55a), color-stop(1, #72b352));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #77b55a 5%, #72b352 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#77b55a', endColorstr='#72b352',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#77b55a;
 -moz-border-radius:4px;
 -webkit-border-radius:4px;
 border-radius:4px;
 border:1px solid #4b8f29;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:6px 12px;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #5b8a3c;
}
.myButton:hover {
 background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #72b352), color-stop(1, #77b55a));
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
 background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
 background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #72b352 5%, #77b55a 100%);
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#72b352', endColorstr='#77b55a',GradientType=0);
 background-color:#72b352;
}
.myButton:active {
 position:relative;
 top:1px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR);
$id="";
$opr="";
if(isset($_GET['opr']))
 $opr=$_GET['opr'];

if(isset($_GET['rs_id']))
 $id=$_GET['rs_id'];
//--------------add data----------------- 


if(isset($_POST['btn_sub'])){
 $grupo=$_POST['grupotxt'];
 $titulo=$_POST['titulotxt'];
 $materia=$_POST['materiatxt'];
 $pregunta=$_POST['pregunta'];
 $respuesta_a=$_POST['respuesta_a'];
 $respuesta_b=$_POST['respuesta_b'];
 $respuesta_c=$_POST['respuesta_c'];
 $respuesta_d=$_POST['respuesta_d'];
 $respuesta_co=$_POST['respuesta_co'];
 $estatus=$_POST['estatustxt'];
 
 $sql_add=mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblmaterial 
       VALUES('$grupo',
        '$titulo',
        '$materia',
        '$pregunta',
        '$pregunta_a',
        '$pregunta_b',
        '$pregunta_c',
        '$pregunta_d',
        '$pregunta_co',
        '$estatus'
       )
      ");
 if($sql_add==true)
  $msg="1 Record inserted...";
 else
  $smg="Insert Fail...".mysql_error();
}

//------------------update data----------
if(isset($_POST['btn_upd'])){
 $grupo=$_POST['grupotxt'];
 $titulo=$_POST['titulotxt'];
 $materia=$_POST['materiatxt'];
 $pregunta=$_POST['pregunta'];
 $respuesta_a=$_POST['respuesta_a'];
 $respuesta_b=$_POST['respuesta_b'];
 $respuesta_c=$_POST['respuesta_c'];
 $respuesta_d=$_POST['respuesta_d'];
 $respuesta_co=$_POST['respuesta_co'];
 $estatus=$_POST['estatustxt'];
 
 $sql_update=mysql_query("UPDATE  tblmaterial SET 
       grupo='$grupo',
       titulo='$titulo',
       materia='$materia',
        pregunta='$pregunta',
        pregunta_a='$pregunta_a',
        pregunta_b='$pregunta_b',
        pregunta_c='$pregunta_c',
        pregunta_d='$pregunta_d',
        pregunta_co='$pregunta_co',
        estatus='$estatus'
       WHERE
       grupo=$id
     ");
     
if($sql_update==true)
 header("location:?tag=view_examen");
else
 $msg="Update Fail!...";
 
 
}
?>



</head>
<body>
<div id="top_style">
            <div id="top_style_text">
                Captura de Preguntas para Examen
            </div>
            <!-- end of top_style_text-->
           <div id="top_style_button"> 
                <form method="post">
                    <a href="?tag=ver_preguntas_examen"><input type="button" name="btn_view" value="Ver Preguntas" id="button_view" style="width:120px;"  /></a>
                 
                </form>
           </div><!-- end of top_style_button-->
    </div><!-- end of top_style-->
    <tr>
             <td>Grupo</td>
             <td>
                 <select name="Grupotxt" id="textbox">
                     <option>---- Grupo   ------</option>
                             <?php
                               $fac_name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblgrupos");
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($fac_name)){
            if($row['grupo']==$rs_upd['grupo'])
             $iselect="selected";
         else
          $iselect="";
        ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row['grupo'];?>" <?php echo $iselect ;?> > <?php echo $row['grupo'];?> </option>
                                <?php 
          }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
 <tr>
                    <td>Titulo </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Titulotxt" id="textbox" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
    <div id="style_informations">
        <form method="post">
            <div>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Materia</td>
                    <td> 
                        <select name="materiatxt" id="textbox">
                     <option>---- Materia   ------</option>
                            <?php
                               $fac_name=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblmaterias");
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($fac_name)){
        ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row['materias'];?>"> <?php echo $row['materias'];?> </option>
                                <?php 
          }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
             <td>Bimestre</td>
             <td>
                 <select name="Bimestretxt" id="textbox">
                     <option>---- Bimestres -----</option>
                         <?php
                            $bimestre=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bimestretbl");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($bimestre)){
        if($row['bimestre']==$rs_upd['bimestre'])
           $iselect="selected";
        else
         $iselect="";
        ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $row['bimestre'];?>" <?php echo $iselect ;?> > <?php echo $row['bimestre'];?> </option>
                                <?php 
          }
                            ?> 
                            
                    </select>
                </td>
    
            </tr>
<center><p>Creador de preguntas Para Examenes Parciales</p></center>

<table id="myexam">
 <tr>
  <th>pregunta</th>
  <th>Respuesta A</th>
  <th>Respuesta B</th>
  <th>Respuesta C</th>
  <th>Respuesta D</th>
  <th>Respuesta Correcta</th>
 </tr>
  
</table>
```

I´am creating a php page where I want to put in my table on mysq, where the website works but I want to put the javascript variables on my php variables to put or write on my table that with my mysql query it works but I cannot find the way to transfer the variables information to my php variables and write over the table... of curse I want when the javascrip query asked for "Desea Agregar Otra pregunta" when I want to continue it write for itself in my table... I need help... To be very honest with out the code

```
"<?php  $var = “<script> document.write(var) </script>”;
                    echo “var = “.$var;
?>"
```

it works and makes that i want but with out write theinfo in my database, and I wish to it be on my database after to put another question... [I leave the picture know what I means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiwCI.jpg)